# combine strings with combn lists in R

Tags: r

I want to loop over combinations created by `combn()`.

Input:

```
"a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Desired Output:

```
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
[1] "a and b" "a and c" "a and d" "b and c" "b and d" "c and d"
[1] "a and b and c" "a and b and d" "a and c and d" "b and c and d"
[1] "a and b and c and d"
```

**What i tried:**

```
classes <- letters[1:4]
cl <- lapply(1:length(classes), combn, x = classes)
apply(cl[[1]], 2, paste, collapse = " and ")
apply(cl[[2]], 2, paste, collapse = " and ")
apply(cl[[3]], 2, paste, collapse = " and ")
apply(cl[[4]], 2, paste, collapse = " and ")
```

Basically my Question is what is the best way to loop over the last part `apply(cl[[NR]], 2, paste, collapse = " and ")`.

I thought about `lapply`, but that i would assign `FUN` twice and it seems odd to combine lapply and apply in one call. For loop is possible but Maybe there is a more efficient way.

If the Question is better suited for Code review, i am happy to migrate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the length of your vector and use the function argument of `combn()` to collapse the output using `paste()`:

```
vec <- letters[1:4]

lapply(seq_along(vec), function(x) combn(vec, x, FUN = paste, collapse = " and "))

[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

[[2]]
[1] "a and b" "a and c" "a and d" "b and c" "b and d" "c and d"

[[3]]
[1] "a and b and c" "a and b and d" "a and c and d" "b and c and d"

[[4]]
[1] "a and b and c and d"
```

Comment: Bingo, `combn()` has an often overlooked `FUN=` argument of its own that applies to each of the combinations.

Comment: thats what i just wanted to write. Never noticed the function Argument. Thanks a lot!